# Colleague's MS Excel 2010 doesn't display tooltip to convert to number

Tags: microsoft-excel

My colleague asked me how to implement a VLOOKUP formula because he was getting an #N/A error message. I highlighted the cells but I did not receive a tooltip like the one shown in the image below (couldn't post image because reputation is too low). I tried to fix the problem by changing the format of the cells (right click, Format Cells...) being referenced by the formula but I couldn't get it to work. I had him email me the file and then I opened it on my computer and when I highlighted the cells in question the tooltip appeared. Is there some kind of Excel configuration that determines if this tooltip appears? (I might be misusing the word tooltip, I mean that yellow box with the ! in it.  Thank you for your help.

[image: http://scholargram.com/4SO.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel sees the values in column P as text strings.  My guess is your VLOOKUP reference are numbers.  Change your formula from `...VLOOKUP(P2...` to `...VLOOKUP(VALUE(P2)...`

Comment: Someone give me rep so I can upvote this guy's answer.

Comment: Thank you ExactaBox who you have in the 5th race at Belmont tomorrow?

Comment: @RichardPullman you'll be able to upvote as soon as you have 15 rep. just one more nice question or answer - and you're done. Good luck!)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a column with the formula "=1*A2" where A2 is the cell which contains the number formatted as text.

Comment: This Also works!